# Create new Field At Account Level

Tags: workflow, custom-field, formula-field, roles

At Account level there is one filed named "Comment(Type-Long Text area)".now i want to create one another field at account level that give the count, Number of "comments" inserted by specific role of the user (ex.abc role) for this month and previous month.

How can i get this count(Number of comment of abc user role)?. is it possible through formula field and any need of workflow or not?

Please help me on this
Thanks

Comment: The part where you want it to show by last month and this month means it has to involve some Apex, probably at least a trigger and a scheduled class. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using trigger.but comment should be in some other child object other than Account. then ask users to create separate comment record every time. On saving the comment you can capture the logged in user role and at the same you can populate aggregated numbers on account.

Thanks,
Raviteja